# Gnuplot 5.2.8: "set logscale", "set clip": no lines drwan to/from 0 (zero ~=~ -inf)

Tags: logging, gnuplot, zero, clip, infinity

When logscale y is set, no (vertical) lines are drawn to/from 0-values (which correspond to -infinity in logscale), independent from the clip value.
E.g. in this (M)WE:

```
reset
$DATA << EOD
10
0.1
9
0.01
8
1e-3
7
1e-4
6
1e-5
5
1e-6
4
1e-7
3
1e-8
2
1e-9
1
0
1
10
EOD
set xrange [*:|$DATA|-1]
set xtics 1
set yrange [0.5:*]
set logscale y
set grid
set style data linespoints
plot $DATA
show clip
```

no (vertical) lines are drawn from (18|1) to (19|0) and from (19|0) to (20|1).

Is there another way to get these lines besides changing the 0-values to something like 1e-99?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect? `log(0)` is not defined, so where should this point be placed?

As you suggest, you can replace `0` with a small value, e.g. `1e-99` or `1e-323` which is probably the smallest value which seems to work.

If you have several `0` values in your data and you don't want to change your data manually and want nevertheless a vertical line drawn downwards, you can define a function which will replace `0` with a very small number.

**Code:**

```
### replace 0 with some very small value
reset session

$Data << EOD
10
0.1
9
0.01
8
1e-3
7
1e-4
6
1e-5
5
1e-6
4
1e-7
3
1e-8
2
1e-9
1
0
1
10
EOD

set xtics 1
set yrange [0.5:*]
set logscale y
set grid

myZero(n) = n==0 ? 1e-323 : n

plot $Data u 0:(myZero($1)) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]